# Hive to Solr Cloud Data Migration

Tags: hadoop, solr, hive, hadoop2, solrcloud

Am working on Hive and Solr Cloud
I have to index the data from hive to solr cloud and i have tried the following links to that no luck for me
http://github.org/chimpler/hive-solr and
https://github.com/vroyer/hive-solr-search

in both cases am getiing the ERROR for STORAGE HANDLER

ERROR WHEN FOLLOWIG 2nd Link

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.vroyer.hive.solr.SolrInputFormat
```

i have copied the hive-solr*.jar into HIVE lib and HADOOP lib in all the master and slave nodes.

hive configured with tez

```
VERSIONS USING:
HADOOP 2.7.1 (Cluster with 3 slaves and one master)
HIVE 1.2.1
SOLR 5.3.1(Clusterd in 3 pc's)
```

I want to index hive data in solr any one can help me what i am missing in it.

Comment: Solr can't find your class. Put jars under `SOLR_BASE/server/solr/YOUR_CORE/lib/`.

Answer (score 1):

There is another tool https://github.com/lucidworks/hive-solr that you could try.

In order to migrate the data from Hive to Solr, you can create a `solr-table` like:

```
  hive> CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE solr (id string, field1 string, field2 int)
        STORED BY 'com.lucidworks.hadoop.hive.LWStorageHandler'
        LOCATION '/tmp/solr'
        TBLPROPERTIES('solr.zkhost' = 'zk.host:2181/solr',
                     'solr.collection' = 'collection1',
                     'solr.query' = '*:*');
```

And then you can insert data into Solr doing SQLlike queries.

```
INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE solr SELECT b.* FROM books b;
```

Where `books` is another table in hive with the same table schema.

Answer (score 0):

build the jar with given code and add jar to hadoop classpath

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to check the built jar contains the desired class and use add jar command to explicitly add the jar into classpath, this would resolve the issue.